# Is it possible to have a spring boot application with Java AND kotlin?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have been trying to build a spring boot application using maven with Java and Koltin. There are no errors, no nothing, but when running it it just says NoDefClassException and doesn't find my exceptions, my repositories, basically anything that comes from kotlin.
Here is my plugins from the pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                 <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaVersion>V2</schemaVersion>
                    <resourceGroup>media-services</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>companysystemservices</appName>
                    <pricingTier>F1</pricingTier>
                    <region>westeurope</region>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>java11</javaVersion>
                        <webContainer>java11</webContainer>
                    </runtime>
                    <deployment>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.jar</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </deployment>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

How can i have them compile and run everything here?

EDIT: My package explorer is something like:

```
src/main/java
   com.company
       annotations
       config
       controllers
       daos
       dtos
       model
       services
       utils
       CompanyApp.java
```

Within the model are 3 kotlin the first containing 10 exceptions, the second 12 repositories and the last 3 sql projections as data classes.

[image: See this is what i mean, The classes are on kotlin bin, seems to work just fine but then doesnt bootstrap the JPA's. and yes i check there is the repository annotation]

I also added a CommandLineRunner and tried to throw an exception, got this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/company/model/BadRequest400Exception
    at com.company.CompanyApplication.run(CompanyApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.company.CompanyApplication.main(CompanyApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.model.BadRequest400Exception
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:144) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Im trying to run it on eclipse locally, and it runs fine on intellij. But eclipse is free so i'd prefer eclipse but can't seem to put it to work.

Comment: Open the artifact that gets created after you run the maven (in the `target` folder) and make sure that kotlin classes are there in the correct folders + all the relevant dependencies are in `BOOT-INF/lib` folder...

Comment: Whats the BOOT-INF/lib folder? In the target it creates the individual classes from kotlin into java classes in the exact same packages

Comment: I have ran the mvnw spring-boot:run and then eclipse works, but each time i edit, i have to re run the command. Seems to me it just doesnt compile kotlin to target

Comment: Can't tell why your specific project is not working. I've worked on multiple java + kotlin projects with spring, never had any issues (all with intellij). But I can comment on this: "But eclipse is free" -> so is intellij, there is a community edition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. As far as I can see in your project structure you have Kotlin code under the java source code. I am using this approach with gradle and IntelliJ but it should work with eclipse and maven.
For example if you have

```
src/main/java
   com.company
       config
           JavaConfig.java
           KotlinConfig.kt
```

you need to separate the java and Kotlin source code.

```
src/main/java
   com.company
       config
           JavaConfig.java
src/main/kotlin
   com.company
       config
           KotlinConfig.kt
```